# Shuffle, then find and replace duplicates in two dimensional array - without sorting

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, replace, duplicates

I'm looking for efficient algorithm (or any at all..) for this tricky thing. I'll simplify my problem. In my application, this array is about 10000 times bigger :)

I have an 2D array like this:

```
0 2 1 3 4
1 2 0 4 3
0 2 1 3 4
4 1 2 3 0
```

Yes, in every row there are values range from 0 to 4 but in different order. The order matters! I can't just sort it and solve this in easy way :)
Then, I shuffle it by choosing a random indexes and swapping them - couple of times. Example result:

```
0 1 1 1 4
1 2 2 4 3
0 2 3 3 4
4 2 0 3 0
```

I see duplicates in the rows, that's not good.. Algorithm should find this duplicates and replace them with a value that will not be another duplicate in particular row, for example:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 0 4 3
0 2 3 1 4
4 2 0 3 1
```

Can you share your ideas? Maybe there is already very famous algorithm for this problem? I'd be grateful for any hint.

EDIT
Clarification for T_G: After the shuffle, particular row can't exchange values with another rows. It need to find duplicates and replace it with available (any) value left - which is not another duplicate.

After shuffling:

```
0 1 1 1 4
1 2 2 4 3
0 2 3 3 4
4 2 0 3 0
```

Steps:
I have `0`; I don't see another zeros. Next.

I have `1`; I see another `1`; I should change it (the second one); there is no `2` in this row, so lets change this duplicate `1` to `2`.

I have 1; I see another `1`. I should change it (the second one); there is no `3` in this row, so lets change this duplicate `1` to `3`. etc...

So if you input this row:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You should get:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: If your goal is to jumble the original 2D array but keeping the constraints you describe, one option might be to swap whole columns and/or rows only rather than individual cells.

Comment: That's a good point but actually this is genetic algorithm related problem and I just have to mix these vectors between themselves :)

Comment: Could you please specify whther the algorithm should "unshuffle" this duplicates making swaps or is it allowed to just substitute a vaule with another value on a specific position ?

Comment: This kind of reminds me of the "N-Queens" problem, perhaps you could look there for some brainstorming?

Comment: Don't you just need to shuffle each row separately?  If each row has no duplicates, then shuffling the row won't create any.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this is another part of the algorithm, which I've done already :)

Comment: Why do you need a full 2d array shuffle?  what you are fixing after the initial shuffle would look no different than simply shuffling rows only as @JonathanLeffler has noted (unless these integers are not actually integers in your real situation, and instead represent IDs/fields of objects?)

Comment: Thx very much for your prompt reply and edit. Regards.

Comment: How does "the order matters" work with "exchanging random indices"?

Comment: "I just have to mix these vectors between themselves" - no, you don't; not as the problem is described. Shuffle each *row*. They start unique self-respectively, so *keep them that way*. That is what you're ultimately going to end with anyway, Why introduce all the additional CPU cycles trying to solve an unnecessary problem that wouldn't be there unless you created it in the first place. If the `1` in row-0 is not equivalent to the `1` in row-N, then you'd better clarify that and *change the fundamentals of your question*, otherwise you're literally making work out of what should be nothing.

Comment: Do you have the list of shuffle permutations?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you can perform 2 additional swaps for each of you current swaps.  When you swap a new value into a row, you can search for the same value in the row and replace it with the old value.  If the number of swaps is much less than the total number of rows then this should be reasonable efficient.

Comment: Actually, unless there are other constraints, can't you just swap random values within a row?

Comment: What is the bigger goal? With as many allowable values as elements in a row, you will end up with a permutation, regardless how you specify which one. Will the bigger array still contain values from 0 to 4, or still contain permutations (0-500) (the example from the 3rd rev. seems to suggest this - be explicit, please)? If it is 0-4, will _the big array_ be tiled with 5x5s, or is the condition "not one of the four values before" (resulting in a repetition to the end of the row)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Iterate matrix lines, line by line
for(uint32_t line_no = 0; line_no < max_line_num; line_no++) {

  // counters for each symbol 0-4; index is symbol, val is counter
  uint8_t counters[6];

  // Clear counters before usage
  memset(0, counters, sizeof(counters));

  // Compute counters
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    counters[matrix[line_no][i]]++;

  // Index of maybe unused symbol; by default is 4
  int j = 4; 

  // Iterate line in reversed order
  for(int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) 
    if(counters[matrix[line_no][i]] > 1) { // found dup
      while(counters[j] != 0) // find unused symbol "j"
        j--;
      counters[matrix[line_no][i]]--; // Decrease dup counter
      matrix[line_no][i] = j; // substitute dup to symbol j
      counters[j]++; // this symbol j is used
    } // for + if
} // for lines
```